# How to download all photos from Google Photos into device?

Tags: backup, restore, gallery, google-photos

I wanted to do a factory reset. I made a backup of my device using "Setting" → "Accounts and backup" → "Google drive" → "Back up data" → "Back up now" →  under "Photos and videos" I checked "Backup photos and videos from this device to your Google Account" checkbox. After one hour the backup completed. I did factory reset, chose to restore from backup and selected the backup file.

Now everything got restored except the Gallery photos. Those photos appear in Google Photos.

I have around 950 photos. How do I download all of them *at once*, so that they become available in my Gallery app?

Comment: "all at once" - there is no such option available in google photos app. you need to download one by one.

Comment: @Gmk but why my android mobile gallery images did not get backuped ? could they be already inside the backup file i have?

Comment: if those gallery images are not backed up means you didn't include that folder (probably it is a different folder other than default camera folder) to backup in google photos. you can include device folders by going to backup settings and select "backup device folders" and select available folders.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a PC.
Login to https://photos.google.com
Select first photo from where you want to download the photos. Press and hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key and then select the last image you want to download. Everything should be selected in between them.

`3 dots --> download`

A zip will be downloaded. Copy that to your phone to `DCIM` folder. Extract. Done

Comment: will check those steps.. but is there any limitations about the number of photos i can select and download using my PC?

Comment: 500 pics at a time :)

Comment: Please consider accepting and upvoting if this helped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,, I can not upvote as i am new... now i downloaded the folder to the PC, then how i can transfer the zip folder to my  phone?

Comment: You can upvote on questions that you have asked. Also you can tap that tick mark to accept the answer... You can use USB to copy the files. You can watch videos on YouTube about it